# Vert.x with sync transaction

Tags: java, vert.x

Good morning,
I have the followed code with Vert.x and I want to access a table to receive response synchronously.

```
  private Future<String> retornaRiscoCalculadoProjeto(String numPrj) {

        Future<String> future = Future.future();

        jdbcClientSync.getConnection(conn -> {

            if (conn.failed()) {
                log.error("Falha ao recuperar a conexão com Sapiens", conn.cause());
                future.fail(conn.cause());
                return;
            }

            String sql = "SELECT TOP 1 obsprj FROM e615obs" +
                    " WHERE numprj = " + "?" +
                    " AND obsprj LIKE '%alterado risco%'" +
                    " ORDER BY SeqObs desc";
            JsonArray params = new JsonArray();

            params.add(numPrj);

            SQLConnection sqlConnection = conn.result();
            sqlConnection.queryWithParams(sql, params, ar -> {

                if (ar.failed()) {
                    log.error("Falha ao recuperar dados do Sapiens", ar.cause());
//                    future.fail(conn.cause());
                    return;
                }

                if (!ar.result().getResults().isEmpty()){
                    future.complete(ar.result().getResults().get(0).getList().get(0).toString());
                }

            }).close();
        });

        return future;
    }
```

How I do to do Vert.x response synchronously like

```
String response = retornaRiscoCalculadoProjeto(number);
```

Tks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Vert.x is async by nature. What you want is to block on the operation to get the String which would essentially break this contract Vert.x expects (see the docs about [blocking](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_don_t_block_me)).

The correct way is to process the results using the `map`-methods provided by `Future`.

In your case  `retornaRiscoCalculadoProjeto(...).map(res -> {...})`.
This can be made nicer by using the rxified APIs which allow for a more rich set of operations.

The key message remains: Don't block!